# change number digit grouping in windows 10

Tags: window, settings

I want my number digit grouping look like following.

[image]

But in my windows 10 system I am getting:

[image]

How to change the number format to: `1234,56,789.00`

Comment: You may have better luck asking at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) as SO is for programming questions

Comment: according to the picture the problem is not the separator